# How can I tell what device or file name I am redirecting to

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

From within a shell script (sh/bash), how can I tell what device or file name I am redirecting to?

For example, I have a shell script named `script.sh`.

I run the shell script and redirect STDOUT to a file named `out.txt`, and redirect STDERR to a file named `err.txt`.

So, that would look like this:

```
$ ./script.sh > out.txt 2> err.txt
```

Now, from within the shell script, I can tell ***if*** STDOUT (or STDERR) is being redirected, or not:

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then...
if [ ! -t 1 ]; then...
```

but, once I know STDOUT (or STDERR) is being redirected, how can I tell ***where*** it is being rdirected to?

Comment: Why would the script need to care?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - The script will run for hours and will generate many Gigabytes of output. I want to (every so often) check the size of the redirect file and restart the script with redirection to a different file if (when) it gets larger than some size (the script is written so that it can be stopped and restarted, and it will resume where it was before it was stopped).

Comment: That's something the external script should be handling. The one that knows where it's redirecting to.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - The script is being started from the command line. I could write a "wrapper" script to start the main script, and the "wrapper" would know the name of the redirect file, but once the "wrapper" calls the main script, the "wrapper" waits (does nothing) until the main script completes and exits... by then, it would be meaningless for the "wrapper" script to check the redirect file anymore.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - If the answer to my question is that ***"it can't be done"***, then I can find workarounds involving various ways of passing the name of the redirect file to the main script, or starting the mainscript in the background, and let the "wrapper" monitor the redirect file. But all this adds levels of unnecessary complexity if what I'm asking can be done.

Comment: It can be done, but 1) it's OS-specific, and 2) it shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `lsof`:

> /usr/sbin/lsof -p $$ -a -d 1

The above would list just file descriptor 1 for just the current process:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
bash    5054 matt    1u   CHR  136,1      0t0    4 /dev/pts/1
```

Comment: Thank you. THis is probably what I wanted. But, unfortunately, **`lsof`** is not found on my machine. Here is my output of uname: **`Linux 3.2.52 #9 SMP Tue Oct 29 11:08:09 CDT 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux`**

Comment: It's found in `/usr/sbin` rather than `/usr/bin`, so if `sbin` isn't the the `PATH` for your script that's the problem.  If it's not in `sbin` either, then use your distribution's package manager to get the `lsof` package.

Comment: Eureka! I found it in `/usr/sbin`. It seems to be working. I ran it as `"/usr/sbin/lsof -p $$ -a -d 1"`, and it came back with hundreds of warnings like: `"lsof: WARNING: can't stat() ext4 file system /home/...folder"`. So, I added the `"-w"` switch. And, in order to only get the file-size and filename, I also added `"-Fsn"`. Running `"/usr/sbin/lsof -p$$ -a -d 1 -w -Fsn"` produced: **`"p1234`** \n **`s288355`** \n **`n/home/...path/filename".`** So, I needed to use `grep` and `sed` to remove the **`"p1234"`** (PID) line, and the leading `"s"` and `"n"` before the file-size and filename.

Answer (score 1):

You generally do things such as "watch" scripts, by watching them from the either the outside or from the script that called this subordinate script.

```
$ ./script.sh > out.txt 2> err.txt &
[1] 6280
```

Now we watch:

```
$ watch "ls -l out.txt err.txt"
Every 2.0s: ls -l out.txt err.txt                        Sun Feb  9 00:30:37 2014

-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb  9 00:30 err.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb  9 00:30 out.txt
```

Every 2 seconds (you can change this) the output will get updated:

```
Every 2.0s: ls -l out.txt err.txt                        Sun Feb  9 00:30:39 2014

-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 200 Feb  9 00:30 err.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 200 Feb  9 00:30 out.txt
```