# Linux Shell fundamentals: How can I check the file descriptors status, (where are redirected to) right now without lsof?

Tags: linux, shell, io-redirection, cygwin

I am learning about **file descriptors** for the case of Linux, and I was wondering if there is any command showing a **complete list** that allows me to know **where is each one redirected** to in this moment.
Maybe some info like:

```
0  -->  <stdin
1  -->  >stdout
2  -->  >stderr
3  -->  >MyFileForWriting
4  -->  <MyFileForReading
```

I have found [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114299/how-can-i-tell-what-device-or-file-name-i-am-redirecting-to) that requires `lsof`, but it could be useful to have another method not depending on that command, if it exists.
I need this info concerning to Linux (I will try it too for CygWin, that does not include the 'lsof' tool until now, but behaves mostly like a POSIX compliant operating system).

Comment: Does cygwin `/proc` filesystem emulation? If so, check out `/proc/PID/fd/`

Comment: Yes, @cpugeniusmv, it does. But will this method work for just the bash shell, when no scripts are running?

Comment: I would imagine it would work for any cygwin-launched processes.

Comment: The Unix & Linux site is for questions pertaining to unix or linux. CygWin questions are more appropriate for [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Thanks, @Patrick. Anyway, I would like to know this answer for non-CygWin Linux systems. My reference to CygWin was just an example of a case where it could be useful another method.

Comment: You have the answer in your question: `lsof` :-)

Comment: Well, I must admit you are right, @Patrick. So I have edited and changed even the title to fit what is, we could say, a new question :-) .

Comment: OK - I don't get it - `/proc/self/fd` is no good? What about `/dev/fd/${num}` - is that a cygwin thing?

Comment: Yes, @mikeserv , both of them do exists at CygWin. Didn't know about the `self` directory in the filesystem. It is a perfect method. Thanks.

Comment: If `lsof` isn't installed, the answer is to install `lsof`. Pretty much every unix variant provides a way to do this, but the way is wildly different between variants. The `lsof` authors provide a single command that works everywhere. If you're going from file name to process, you can also use `fuser`. If you're only interested in Cygwin, use Process Explorer.

Comment: @Gilles, so you mean the answer of @michas about `ls -l /proc/self/fd` will not be valid for all cases?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez This only works on Linux, on Cygwin which emulates that aspect of Linux, and on a few [SysV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V) unices. It doesn't work on other unices, in particular *BSD. In contrast, `lsof` has been ported to any unix you can name and several you can't.

Comment: Well, @Gilles, there is at least one pseudo operating system where `lsof`: CygWin. Anyway, I have reworded the original question in an attempt to fit the rules. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/proc` file system will list exactly this information:

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 michas users 1 Apr  6 04:44 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 michas users 1 Apr  6 04:44 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 michas users 1 Apr  6 04:44 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 michas users 1 Apr  6 04:44 3 -> /proc/6934/fd
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd 2>/dev/null <<<foo |cat
total 0
lr-x------ 1 michas users 1 Apr  6 04:45 0 -> /tmp/sh-thd-361068043 (deleted)
l-wx------ 1 michas users 1 Apr  6 04:45 1 -> pipe:[136729]
l-wx------ 1 michas users 1 Apr  6 04:45 2 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 michas users 1 Apr  6 04:45 3 -> /proc/6952/fd
```

If you are interested in some other process just replaces "self" with the corresponding PID.

Comment: One important item of note is that when shell scripting, doing something like `ls /proc/self` will show the FDs of `ls`, not of the shell invoking `ls`. It's an easy trap to fall into and why I never use it. The way to look at the shell would be `ls -l /proc/$$/fd`

Comment: Correct. But exactly this fact allows easy redirection for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick points out in the comments below that access to these files requires a non-default kernel compile-time option. I was not aware of this having only now discovered them at all. Though I do know that my kernel package was installed via package-manager and so it must be included in the default build at least for one distribution - so your mileage may vary, especially if Cygwin is involved.

I think you'd get a more complete listing if, at least, you included `/proc/self/map_files:`

```
% sudo ls -al ${p=/proc/$$}/map_files | sudo sort -t\> -ubk2,2  

lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 400000-4a6000 -> /usr/bin/zsh
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e05aa3000-7f5e05ac3000 -> /usr/lib/ld-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e04b88000-7f5e04b8c000 -> /usr/lib/libattr.so.1.1.0
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e04d8d000-7f5e04f2b000 -> /usr/lib/libc-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e0589f000-7f5e058a3000 -> /usr/lib/libcap.so.2.24
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e0569b000-7f5e0569e000 -> /usr/lib/libdl-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e05135000-7f5e05235000 -> /usr/lib/libm-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e05436000-7f5e05496000 -> /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5.9
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e0497c000-7f5e04987000 -> /usr/lib/libnss_files-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e05afa000-7f5e05c83000 -> /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e0450c000-7f5e0452f000 -> /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/complete.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e038e0000-7f5e038ee000 -> /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/complist.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e036cb000-7f5e036db000 -> /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/computil.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e03cf3000-7f5e03cfc000 -> /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/parameter.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e03aef000-7f5e03af2000 -> /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/stat.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e04101000-7f5e04103000 -> /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/terminfo.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e04731000-7f5e04773000 -> /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zle.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e03efe000-7f5e03f00000 -> /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zleparameter.so
lr-------- 1 mikeserv mikeserv ? 64 Apr  5 21:07 7f5e04304000-7f5e0430b000 -> /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zutil.so
```

That's a sorted unique list. The list looks very close to this:

```
% lsof -p ${p##*/}

COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
zsh     23748 mikeserv  cwd    DIR    0,3        0 7800580 /proc/23748/map_files
zsh     23748 mikeserv  rtd    DIR   0,33      254     256 /
zsh     23748 mikeserv  txt    REG   0,33   705496 1281560 /usr/bin/zsh
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1281560 /usr/bin/zsh (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1281593 /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/computil.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1281592 /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/complist.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1281579 /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/stat.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1281576 /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/parameter.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1281596 /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zleparameter.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1281582 /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/terminfo.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1281587 /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zutil.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1281591 /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/complete.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1281595 /usr/lib/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zle.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1936654 /usr/lib/libnss_files-2.19.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30            23825 /usr/lib/libattr.so.1.1.0 (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1936661 /usr/lib/libc-2.19.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1936618 /usr/lib/libm-2.19.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30            24316 /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5.9 (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1936627 /usr/lib/libdl-2.19.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1249113 /usr/lib/libcap.so.2.24 (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1936645 /usr/lib/ld-2.19.so (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30          1720288 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive (path dev=0,33)
zsh     23748 mikeserv    0u   CHR  136,6      0t0       9 /dev/pts/6
zsh     23748 mikeserv    1u   CHR  136,6      0t0       9 /dev/pts/6
zsh     23748 mikeserv    2u   CHR  136,6      0t0       9 /dev/pts/6
zsh     23748 mikeserv   10u   CHR  136,6      0t0       9 /dev/pts/6
```

Well, the filenames do anyway. I think a lot of this functionality could be easily reproduced with just `stat,` possibly `ps` and/or the pid of interest. Obviously there's the `fd` directory, as mentioned in the other answer, and you can get root, cwd, from the `/proc/self` filesystem as well.

Comment: I would clarify that this shows memory mapped files, not normal opened files (accessible via file descriptor). It's also not enabled in most kernels. It defaults to `n` (disabled), and isn't even accessible unless `CONFIG_EXPERT` is also enabled.

Comment: Even /proc/maps? I just found this stuff so I'm learning about it - but the question seemed to me to ask how to replicate `lsof's` output. In any case, `lsof` lists them as mem-mapped FDs which indicated file descriptors. Also, if you `cat` one of these memory blocks you'll see the actual currently mapped file - or the blocks of it in memory, anyway.

Comment: Note that your replacement for `lsof` *only* lists the memmapped files and does not list the file descriptors the process has open (the bottom 4 lines of your `lsof` output) that the OP is specifically asking about.

Comment: @casey It's not a replacement - personally, I wouldn't use `ls` at all - I point out at the bottom that the files included in the other answer should be included also and the current working directory and so on. I also suggest `stat` and/or `ps` would probably be the goto tools here - not `ls` - did you read it? Actually I point that out top and bottom - I just called it a *more* complete listing. But `lsof` does call them file descriptors FDs, anyway

Comment: Yes I did, I read both the Q (did you?) and your A, which why I was compelled to comment.  The Q isn't asking to reproduce the `lsof` output, it is looking to get the file descriptor information via a different command than `lsof`.  To be clear, I'm not disagreeing with anything you say in your A, I'm just pointing out much of it just isn't relevant to the question posed.

Comment: @casey You would say that memory mapped file descriptors are irrelevant to to this: *"I am learning about file descriptors, and I was wondering if there is any command showing a complete list that allows me to know where is each one redirected to in this moment."..?* The asker even bolded **complete, each one** and the like. I'm just trying to give the guy options - I'm not asking for a paycheck. And it definitely is relevant - that just means related. Certainly the above must be related if I found it researching the question - at least to some degree.

Comment: @mikeserv yes, and then he qualified what he meant by "complete" and "each one" with his example output of numbered file descriptors and their target.

Comment: @casey That's what the above does too - I even used the pointer character as the `sort` delimiter. What are we even arguing about?

Comment: @Patrick - this was quite by accident, but reading through the kernel `/proc/` docs and I happened upon the mention of `/proc/$$/map_files`. It's the `CONFIG_CHECKPOINT_RESTORE` option you need. And you can get the same info out of `/proc/$$/maps` without any special compilation settings at all. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: @mikeserv see line [Kconfig line 1092](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/Kconfig?id=a7963eb7f4c4b5df84d5dd5083734278ad75bafb#n1092), the `if EXPERT` bit. This means the `EXPERT` option must be enabled, which is not normal. This is what I was referring to. You can get the info out of `maps` yes, but what `map_files` lets you do is get access to the files themselves, not something you could do otherwise.

Comment: @Patrick You would be able to... kind of. If I'm reading it right, looks like you can get the path to the actual file from `../maps`, but `../map_files` are the actual in-kernel memory regions, I think. If you `cat` them they're not complete. But yeah - thanks for clarifying. It's a dependency then, so you'd need both config options then, huh? Weird that it's enabled for me, though. Is it for you?